# Arduino-powered silent relay needed. Will AQV210E work?

Tags: arduino, relay

I'm trying to find a small, affordable, solid-state SPST relay that I can use for an Arduino project.  I've made an analog clock using regular electromechanical relays, and it works fine.  But the clicks (once every 15 seconds) are driving (especially) my wife and me crazy!

I have found a 6-pin DIP SSR, a Panasonic chip called "AQV210E" (https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/AQV210E/255-1143-5-ND/251915), with a detailed description that reads:
Solid State SPST-NO (1 Form A) 6-DIP (0.300", 7.62mm)

It looks to me as if the AQV210E will work, as long as I use appropriate resistance for its input (Arduino uses +5v or 0v digital pin output signal, and this chip's input is rated for only 1.14vdc).  It seems to me (I admit I'm a novice/hobbyist) that the input of this chip should behave just like any LED being powered by a 5vdc signal... correct resistance between Arduino digital pin output and AQV210E chip input should allow successful On/Off behavior without frying the AQV210E.

Output-wise, I'll be making and breaking a ground connection for one or two LEDs at a time, so very little current is involved.  The AQV201E isn't a zero-crossing relay, and it appears to be useful for a DC in / DC out application.

Can someone tell me if this AQV210E chip might work for me?

Comment: you are asking if the SSR is suitable for switching an unknown load

Comment: Why don't you just use an NPN transistor?

Comment: Why does your clock rely on relays?  For timed activation of something that could be reasonable, but it's innapropriate for just being a clock.  This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: jsotola, The "unknown load" is apparently successfully hidden in my question.  It says, "Output-wise, I'll be making and breaking a ground connection for one or two LEDs at a time..."  That's the load.

Comment: Chris Stratton, It's not the clock, exactly, that needs the relays.  The Arduino Mega I'm using doesn't have enough pins to control the LED that represents each second, minute, and hour with separate signals. I'd need 132 pins just for those features, to say nothing of other things the clock does.  So I'm using relays to connect the grounds of the LEDs in blocks of seconds LEDs, minutes LEDs, and hours LEDs.  Using 7 SPST relays, I can reduce the number of required pins to just 39.  It works great - just clicky with electromechanical relays!

Comment: Elliott Alderson, I'm pretty new to electronics - just a hobbyist.  The NPN transistor idea is a good one - I just didn't think about it (mostly because I AM new to tinkering with electronic devices).  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: if you are switching DC, use a MOSFET; they are basically SSRs w/o isolation (which is not often actually needed). You can add an optocoupler if you need isolation.

Comment: dandavis, Thanks for the MOSFET idea.  Again, being a newcomer to electronics, there are all sorts of things I can learn.  I'll do some MOSFET research so I can put that tool into my toolbox.  (I'm going to need a bigger toolbox soon.  That's a good thing!)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about driving it like a typical LED.  \$R=\frac{Vcc-Vf}{I}\$

Drive it with enough current (\$I\$) to cause the output to switch on fully (Looks like 1.6mA to 3.0mA is their max required turn on current.  They characterize it with 5mA though in the graphs).
For the load side, it can only handle 130mA, so do not exceed that.

Tick - Tock -Tick -Tock ... silence...

Comment: Aaron, It's nice to hear that I might be on the right track.  Thank you!